# Get all elements with certain class except within certain parents

Tags: javascript

I would like to get all elements with certain class except those within parents with specific class using vanilla javascript?

So I have something like this:

```
<div class="exclude">
    <img class="img"/>
    <img class="img"/>
    <img class="img"/>
</div>

<div>
    <img class="img"/>
    <img class="img"/>
    <img class="img"/>
</div>

<img class="img"/>
<img class="img"/>
<img class="img"/>

<div class="exclude">
    <div>
        <img class="img"/>
    </div>
    <img class="img"/>
    <img class="img"/>
</div>
```

I would like to get all elements with the class of "img" except those within the element of class "exclude". So in this case I would get 6 elements.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you all the images excluding the ones under `exclude`

```
const result = document.querySelectorAll(":not(.exclude) > .img")
```

Comment: Right, what if the images would be located further dom the dom tree? Something like this: ".exclude" > div > div > ".img"?

I'm guessing the ":not(.exclude) > .img" will find all images if they are direct children of ".exclude"? I've updated the question.